# in jquery, match the first next element

Tags: jquery

I have a href tag, and next to it is a  tag.  I want to put new text in between the bold tags.

```
<a href=""></a> <b>old text</b>
```

So in my click handler, how can I get a reference to the text between the bold tag?

I know there is $(this + b) but how do I make sure it only gets the first and not ALL next items (like in the jquery sample).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the b-tag with:

```
$(this).next();
```

Get the text inside the b-tag with:

```
$(this).next().text();
```

And set the text inside the b-tag with:

```
$(this).next().text("Something new");
```

Answer (score 24):

Even though Magnar's answer has been marked as the accepted one, it doesn't actually answer the original question (necessarily). That's a problem when reaching this question from a search. Maybe the question needs to be reworded. Anyway, my point is that this will fail if there's another element in between 'a' and 'b'. To *really* match the 'first, next' element, use:

```
$('a').nextAll('b:first')
```

Note that Tim Büthe's answer is also incorrect (it could match a previous sibling).

Comment: I know its an old answer, but this comes up when searching by google for "jquery show next first" - and bobby´s answer is the only one that always worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You also could do:

```
$(this).siblings(":first").text("Something new");
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, keep all of these in your toolbox, they are all very handy at traversing and they all can accept selectors (#myid, .myclass, etc) and filters (:visible, :first, :odd, etc)

```
.parent()
.sibling()
.children()
.next()
.prev()
```